# Как продолжить работать в главной программе со строкой ,созданной в функции?

Tags: c

Есть вызов функции

```
                     char *r;
r=encodefunc(Skokonada, num2);
```

Её прототип записал так : `char*  encodefunc(int,char*);`

Сама шапка функции выглядит так : `char* encodefunc(int Skokonada,char *num2)`

В этой функции делаю всякие действия и там же создаю новый массив `numfromAscii`
И возвращаю указатель на него `return numfromAscii;`

Вопрос : Как продолжить пользоваться созданным массивом из функции в главной программе ? У меня ведь только адрес с нулевым указателем на массив `numfromAscii` есть

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. У вас есть адрес выделенной памяти, что еще нужно?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, что будет лежать в указателе r ? И как получить доступ к тому созданному массиву из функции ?

Comment: вы возвращаете адрес, значит и `r ` будет содержать адрес этого массива.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский,получается у указателя r теперь выделана память и там лежит то же , что и в массиве из функции ?

Comment: да, но неправильно говорить, что "у указателя r теперь выделена память". Вы выделили память единожды в функции, вернули адрес, а `r` и указывает на тот самый участок памяти.

Comment: @Elvin, только следите чтобы массив в функции выделялся не на стеке.

Comment: **массив в функции выделялся не на стеке** - но тогда эту память нужно будет освобождать вручную.  Лично я в таких ситуациях поступаю таким образом: *cp=strdup(encodefunc(...));* Т.е. я копирую буфер из функции в вызывающую программу, до того, как его удалит менеджер памяти.